# Passing arrays from VBA to VB.NET

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, com, excel-interop

I am working on a vb.net COM interop to work in Microsoft Excel and I am having trouble passing arrays from vb to vb.net. I have a `PointPairs` property in the vb.net code that I need to set from vb and I am having trouble passing the 2 dimensional array. I have tried both setting the property explicitly with a 2D array as well as passing two 1D arrays into a Sub to try and set the property in vb.net, but nothing I have tried seems to work.

vb.net code:

```
Public Property PointPairs() As Double(,)
   Get
     ...
     Return array
   End Get
   Set(ByVal Value(,) As Double)
     ...
   End Set
End Property

Public Sub SetPointPairs(ByRef spline As Spline, ByRef xValues() As Double, _
                              ByRef yValues() As Double)
   Dim Value(,) As Double
   ReDim Value(1, UBound(xValues, 1))

   For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(xValues, 1)
       Value(0, i) = xValues(i)
       Value(1, i) = yValues(i)
   Next

   spline.PointPairs = Value
End Sub
```

vb code:

```
Dim spline1 As New Spline
Dim points(), xValues(), yValues() As Double
'read input from excel cells into points() array/add x and y values to respective arrays

spline1.PointPairs = points 'first method (doesn't work)
Call SetPointPairs(spline1, xValues, yValues)  'second method (doesn't work)
```

Everything is being exported correctly by vb.net and the properties/subs/functions are visible in the Object Browser in vba, however when I try to pass arrays in these two approaches I get error messages `Function or interfaces markes as restricted, or the function uses an automation type not supported in Visual Basic` or `Sub or Function not defined`. I have also tried using `<MarshalAs()>` but I have never used it before and can't find much documentation on how to use it for passing arrays between vb and vb.net.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested in the solution, I found this article that was exactly what I needed.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12386/Sending-an-array-of-doubles-from-Excel-VBA-to-C-us?fid=247508&select=2478365&tid=2478365

I had to break up the 2D array into two 1D arrays of Doubles in VBA and pass them into vb.net as objects and modify them as outlined in the article. I changed the SetPointPairs Sub as follows and added this Private Function to convert from Object to Array in the .net code

```
Sub SetPointPairs(ByRef spline As CubicSpline, ByRef xValues As Object, ByRef yValues As Object) Implements iCubicSpline.SetPointPairs

        Dim xDbls(), yDbls(), pointDbls(,) As Double

        xDbls = ComObjectToDoubleArray(xValues)
        yDbls = ComObjectToDoubleArray(yValues)
        ReDim pointDbls(1, UBound(xDbls, 1))
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(pointDbls, 2)
            pointDbls(0, i) = xDbls(i)
            pointDbls(1, i) = yDbls(i)
        Next

        spline.PointPairs = pointDbls

End Sub

Private Function ComObjectToDoubleArray(ByVal comObject As Object) As Double()

        Dim thisType As Type = comObject.GetType
        Dim dblType As Type = Type.GetType("System.Double[]")
        Dim dblArray(0) As Double

        If thisType Is dblType Then
            Dim args(0) As Object
            Dim numEntries As Integer = CInt(thisType.InvokeMember("Length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, _
                                            Nothing, comObject, Nothing))
            ReDim dblArray(numEntries - 1)
            For j As Integer = 0 To numEntries - 1
                args(0) = j
                dblArray(j) = CDbl(thisType.InvokeMember("GetValue", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
                                        Nothing, comObject, args))
            Next
        End If

        Return dblArray

    End Function
```