# Marshalling a .Net function that returns Double() to consume in VBA

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, com-interop

Here is my function in .Net:

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)>
Public Function Unhex(hex As String) As Double()
    Dim GetArr As Double() = HexStringToDoubleArray(hex)
    Return GetArr
End Function
```

Here is how I would like to use it in VBA:

```
Dim ret() As Double
ret = LinkToComLib.Unhex("EDC531...")
```

There are hundreds of examples of how to pass arrays *into* .Net [(eg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552107/passing-arrays-from-vba-to-vb-net), but the only one I found showing the opposite is [this MS page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146633(v=vs.110).aspx), and it doesn't show it being used on the VBA (or even COM) side. Perhaps I am using the wrong search terms. In any event:

1. Can I use the `MarshalAs` to export the `Double()` from .Net, or will I need to use `Marshal.Copy` or similar (as I suspect, as it is managed)?
2. If I do have to `Copy`, is the proper return type then `IntPtr`?
3. Am I correct in thinking that `Dim ret() As Double` is a pointer to a malloc'ed array or perhaps SAFEARRAY? Is that the proper type to use in VBA in this case?
4. Would creating the array with the proper size (it's always 492!) in VBA and then passing that to the function help in any way? Deallocing perhaps?

If anyone has a pointer to an example of this - a double (or int) array being passed out of .Net along with the corresponding VBA code, I can likely take it from there. But if someone has answers for the above, VB.Net or C# as they like, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try `Dim ret() As Variant`.

Comment: The docs don't pay much attention to anything that works without doing anything special.  Please update the question to explain what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate the return with [`<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

VB.Net Example:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComClass(ArrayExample.ClassId, ArrayExample.InterfaceId)> _
Public Class ArrayExample
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class  and its COM interfaces.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "e510d899-dad1-412b-94ea-6c726fe9f9da"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "ef3498f0-22b4-4c2a-aeb1-22936c9757eb"

    Public Function Unhex(hex As String) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)> Double()
        Dim GetArr As Double() = {2.0R, 5.0R}
        Return GetArr
    End Function
End Class
```

VBA Usage:

```
Sub t()
   Dim c As ExampleComArrayReturn.ArrayExample
   Set c = New ExampleComArrayReturn.ArrayExample
   Dim arr() As Double
   arr = c.Unhex("AABB")
End Sub
```

Edit:  Forgot to mention that this uses the [ComClassAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.comclassattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to have the compiler generate the interfaces for your class.

---

Edit 2 in response to follow-up question.

To debug your COM library project, go to the Debug tab of project properties.  Select "Start External Program" and set it to run Excel.  You can also specify the Workbook to open in the "Command line Arguments".  Now when you click on the "Start" button, Excel will be launched and break points in your code will be triggered.

[image: Setup Run External Application]

---

Edit 3:

To address the issue of targeting .Net 3.5, you can use a slightly less convenient method of attaching the debugger to the Excel process.  If you are using VS2008, the method described above will work.  New VS versions will need to attach to the process. There may be a way to specify this info in the vproj.user file, but I have not found the magic property type to allow direct launching using a specific framework version.

Depending on your VS version the "Attach To Process" item will either be under the Tools (VS2013) or the Debug (VS2017) menu or you can use the shortcut cntrl-alt-p.

Obviously start Excel and load your Workbook.  Then in VS launch the Attach to Process dialog.  Click the "Select" button and then click on the "Debug these type" radiobutton.  Select the "Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0) code" type and click the "OK" button.  Then select the Excel process and click "Attach".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tn! Out of curiousity, can I attach the VS debugger to the VBA code to debug the code as it gets more complex?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to get that going now, it's not finding the PDB and I'm trying to figure out where it's looking for them. UPDATE: I should mention there is a PDB and it's in the same dir as the DLL and the test excel file

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, do you have Excel referencing a dll/tlb that is not in your project's debug folder?  If so, I recommend that while you are in development, that you change that.  You will have to unreference the project in the VBA editor, save the project close Excel as it holds a reference, and then reconnect.

Comment: No luck on the symbols, no refs other than VBA and Excel14. More oddities: 
        MsgBox(hex)
        Dim GetArr As Double() = {2.0R, 5.0R}
        MsgBox(GetArr)
        Return GetArr

Comment: Ahhh, just a VS issue - changed the Framework to 4.5.1 and back and presto, there's my symbols!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, I'm glad you figured it out.  One final piece of info for you though.  If you develop any ActiveX controls, be aware of the insidious Office `*.exd` files.  These are a cached version of control that Office apps make.  They can drive you nuts trying to figure why your changes are not showing up.  They are named "AssemblyName.exd" located in "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Forms" and are safe to delete.

Comment: And one more for the next person that ends up here: if you want debugging to show up when launching an external program (perhaps only COM?), .Net 3.5 doesn't seem to work, I needed at least 4.x. (Client Profile is fine).